# What's a good return value in case a function fails?

Tags: javascript

Had this problem already several times: I've got to program a function in JavaScript.

In know how to check if the required parameter has been assigned. I also know how to check data-type correction.

When one of the checks fail I like to terminate the function by using return.

The thing I'm unsure about: What value shall I return in case of failure?

Some people use 0 or -1 ...

I've seen people doing something like ...

```
if (x === undefined) return
```

... what results in the return of undefined.

Or shall I throw an exception instead of using a return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value has no meaning until you decide to handle it. This means you can make them whatever you like, as long as you are handling them accordingly from the other side. for example:

```
function foo(){
  if(goodstuff){
   //do good stuff
  }else{
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Returning 1 here doesn't inherently mean anything. 1 or -1 are simply common return values for an error. The key is for you to handle the "error" when the function is called:

```
var success = foo();

if( success === 1){
  alert('error');
}else{
  //do stuff
}
```

you can return false, null, 0, "oopsies" or whatever other value makes sense for your situation. The only thing that matters is that you handle it accordingly. Generally returning false or 0 makes for the simplest check, which is why they are commonly used.

To answer your other question, simply doing `return;` will just terminate the function without sending back a value. This is useful if you don't necessarily need to return an error code, but simply just don't want the rest of the code in the function to execute. For example:

```
function bar(){
  if(notAWinner){
    return;
  }

  alert('you win a million dollars!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks you both. @James Thorpe Would like to vote your answer up. But haven't the right to do so. Sorry! You're answer was useful to me too.